# How can I apply styles to specific cells on Material-Table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styles, material-table

Is it possible to style specific cells on Material-Tab (https://material-table.com/#/)? For example, I want to apply background-color to the cells where birth year = 2017:

Please advice! I would be very grateful! =)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ot3lC.png)

Answer (score -1):

```
 <TableCell style={birthYear === 2017 ? {backGround: "#ccc"} : {}}>
  {birthYear}
 </TableCell>
```

Apply color you like and use proper condition.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am using https://material-table.com/#/. I do not have the '<TableCell>' tags. I am just passing the data and they are automatically generated.